# Custom Rolling Computation

Tags: google-bigquery

Assume I have a model that has `A(t)` and `B(t)` governed by the following equations:

```
A(t) = {
  WHEN B(t-1) < 10 : B(t-1)
  WHEN B(t-1) >=10 : B(t-1) / 6
}

B(t) = A(t) * 2
```

The following table is provided as input.

```sql
SELECT * FROM model ORDER BY t;
```

```
| t | A    | B    |
|---|------|------|
| 0 | 0    | 9    |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | null | null |
| 3 | null | null |
| 4 | null | null |
```

I.e. we know the values of `A(t=0)` and `B(t=0)`.

For each row, we want to calculate the value of `A` & `B` using the equations above.

The final table should be:

```
| t | A | B  |
|---|---|----|
| 0 | 0 | 9  |
| 1 | 9 | 18 |
| 2 | 3 | 6  |
| 3 | 6 | 12 |
| 4 | 2 | 4  |
```

---

We've tried using lag, but because of the models' recursive-like nature, we end up only getting `A` & `B` at `(t=1)`

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION A_fn(b_prev FLOAT64) AS (
  CASE
    WHEN b_prev < 10 THEN b_prev
    ELSE b_prev / 6.0
  END
);

SELECT
t,
CASE WHEN t = 0 THEN A ELSE A_fn(LAG(B) OVER (ORDER BY t)) END AS A,
CASE WHEN t = 0 THEN B ELSE A_fn(LAG(B) OVER (ORDER BY t)) * 2 END AS B
FROM model
ORDER BY t;
```

Produces:

```
| t | A    | B    |
|---|------|------|
| 0 | 0    | 9    |
| 1 | 9    | 18   |
| 2 | null | null |
| 3 | null | null |
| 4 | null | null |
```

Each row is dependent on the row above it. It seems it should be possible to compute a single row at a time, while iterating through the rows? Or does BigQuery not support this type of windowing?

If it is not possible, what do you recommend?

Comment: BigQuery does not support iterations - but there is always workaround (or almost always) - so, how many rows you have in your real data that needs to be processed the way you described?

Comment: Is the workaround to use JS UDF? ;) It could be billions.

Comment: i had in mind JS UDF - but billions might not fit into respective limits :o(

Comment: i feel, I have something else in mind :o) stay tuned - will jump into it when have spare time

Comment: Thank you @MikhailBerlyant - in the interim, could you point me in a direction? Happy to also put a bounty on the question (not eligible for 2 days, tho)

Comment: lol - I am not bounty driven - just love to help here

Comment: we really appreciate it.

Comment: The example given was simplified such that the first handful of rows produce INTs. In our real, practical application, A and B are both FLOAT values. We cannot round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Round #1** - starting point

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and works (for me) with up to 3M rows

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION x(v FLOAT64, t INT64)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<t INT64, v FLOAT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var i, result = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= t; i++) { 
    if (v < 10) {v = 2 * v} 
    else {v = v / 3};
    result.push({t:i, v});
  };
  return result
""";
SELECT 0 AS t, 0 AS A, 9 AS B UNION ALL 
SELECT line.t, line.v / 2, line.v FROM UNNEST(x(9, 3000000)) line
```

[image]

Going above 3M rows produces `Resources exceeded during query execution: UDF out of memory.`
To overcome this  - i think you should just implement it on the client - so no JS UDF Limits are applied. I think it is reasonable "workaround" because looks like anyway you have no really data in BQ and just one starting value (9 in this example). But even if you do have other valuable columns in the table  - you can then JOIN produced result back to table ON t value - so should be Ok!

> **Round #2** - It could be billions ... - so let's take care of scale, parallelization

Below is a little trick to avoid JS UDFs Resource and/or Memory error
So, I was able to run it for <kbd>**2B rows in one shot!**</kbd>

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION anchor(seed FLOAT64, len INT64, batch INT64)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<t INT64, v FLOAT64>> LANGUAGE js AS """
  var i, result = [], v = seed;
  for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) { 
    if (v < 10) {v = 2 * v} else {v = v / 3};
    if (i % batch == 0) {result.push({t:i + 1, v})};
  }; return result
""";
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION x(value FLOAT64, start INT64, len INT64)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<t INT64, v FLOAT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var i, result = []; result.push({t:0, v:value});
  for (i = 1; i < len; i++) { 
    if (value < 10) {value = 2 * value} else {value = value / 3};
    result.push({t:i, v:value});
  }; return result
""";
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.result` AS
WITH settings AS (SELECT 9 init, 2000000000 len, 1000 batch), 
  anchors  AS (SELECT line.* FROM settings, UNNEST(anchor(init, len, batch)) line)
SELECT 0 AS t, 0 AS A, init AS B FROM settings UNION ALL
SELECT a.t + line.t, line.v / 2, line.v
FROM settings, anchors a, UNNEST(x(v, t, batch)) line
```

In above query - you "control" initial values in below line

```sql
WITH settings AS (SELECT 9 init, 2000000000 len, 1000 batch),
```

in above example, `9` is initial value, 2,000,000,000 is number of rows to be calculated and 1000 is a batch to process with (*this is important one to keep BQ Engine out of throwing Resource and/or Memory error - you cannot make it too big or too small - i feel I got some sense of what it needs to be - but not enough for trying to formulate it*)

Some stats (settings - execution time):

```sql
  1M: SELECT 9 init,    1000000 len,  1000 batch  -  0 min  9 sec   
 10M: SELECT 9 init,   10000000 len,  1000 batch  -  0 min 50 sec
100M: SELECT 9 init,  100000000 len,   600 batch  -  3 min  4 sec
100M: SELECT 9 init,  100000000 len,    40 batch  -  2 min 56 sec   
  1B: SELECT 9 init, 1000000000 len, 10000 batch  - 29 min 39 sec
  1B: SELECT 9 init, 1000000000 len,  1000 batch  - 27 min 50 sec
  2B: SELECT 9 init, 2000000000 len,  1000 batch  - 48 min 27 sec
```

> **Round #3** - some thoughts and comments

Obviously, as I mentioned in #1 above - **this type of calculation is more suited for being implemented on client of your choice** - so it is hard for me to judge practical value of above - but I really had fun playing with it! In reality, I had few more cool ideas in mind and also implemented and played with them - but above (in #2) was the most practical/scalable one

Note: The most interesting part of above solution is `anchors` table. It is very cheap to generate and allows to set anchors in batch-size interval - so having this you can for example calculate value of row = 2,000,035 or 1,123,456,789 (for example) without actually processing all previous rows - and this will take fraction of sec. Or you can parallelize calculation of all rows by starting several threads/calculations using respective anchors, etc. Quite a number of opportunities.

Finally, it really depends on your specific use-case which way to go further - so I am leaving it up to you

Comment: *Very* helpful @Mikhail. I am trying to adapt to our use-case. The community is grateful for your contributions. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to get it working! Actually, I misspoke previously. There are indeed billions of rows in our table, but each call into the UDF is limited to 1 partition at a time. We have 100k+ of query-level partitions, but in a single partition each row represents 1 hour. I believe it would take 340+ yrs of data to exhaust these limits. (365*24*340 ~= 3M). I found myself on several SO answers of yours to piece together the end query. Although I do not need the `anchor` parallel trick yet, it's invaluable to others & good to keep in my back pocket. Happy you had fun. Accepting & Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> It seems it should be possible to compute a single row at a time, while iterating through the rows

Support for [**Scripting**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) and [**Stored Procedures**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure) is now in beta (as of October 2019)

You can submit multiple statements separated with semi-colons and BigQuery is able to run them now.

So, conceptually your process could look like below script:

```
DECLARE b_prev FLOAT64 DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE t INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE arr ARRAY<STRUCT<t INT64, a FLOAT64, b FLOAT64>> DEFAULT [STRUCT(0, 0.0, 9.0)];

SET b_prev = 9.0 / 2;

LOOP
  SET (t, b_prev) = (t + 1, 2 * b_prev);
  IF t >= 100 THEN LEAVE;
  ELSE
    SET b_prev = CASE WHEN b_prev < 10 THEN b_prev ELSE b_prev / 6.0 END;
    SET arr = (SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(arr, [(t, b_prev, 2 * b_prev)]));
  END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT * FROM UNNEST(arr);
```

Even though above script is simpler and more directly represents logic for non-technical personal and easier to manage - it does not fit in scenarios were you need to loop through more than 100 or more iterations. For example above script took close to 2 min while my original solution for same 100 rows took just 2 sec
But still great for simple / smaller cases